# Vim :colorscheme on Python

Tags: python, macos, vim, syntax-highlighting, osx-lion

I'm using Mac OSX Lion 10.7.2, Terminal.app supports 256 (output of :echo &t_Co).
In my vimrc I have (PATH/TO/vim/vimrc)

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set nobackup
```

When I "vim blah.py" and `:colorscheme torte`, syntax colors are not loading. For example python keyword doesn't have a proper colors (They have regular text color). That works for .c files but not python.

I updated my syntax/python.vim but still no luck.

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

markfw

Your answer is very good but let me just add one thing to it. In your `.vimrc` instead of adding just

```
let python_highlight_all=1
```

you should add it this way

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py let python_highlight_all=1
```

This way it only applies to Python file(s).

Hope this help.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it's more complete than mine. Thank you.

Comment: Put it in `syntax/python.vim`

Answer (score 7):

if it works in c but not on py, the filetype file and/or syntax file is not at the right location for python.

[vim manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_43.html) should help you, but I also would try `:scr` command.  This lists all the vim script loaded.  So you start vim in two different way

`vim your.c`

`vim your.py`

and then in each vim session, type :scr.  see how the syntax file for C is loaded (it is like chain reaction), and why it doesnt work that way for python may give you clue.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I did what you said. Still not working. They are the same except that indent and syntax are different. I see that colors has been loaded. I don't think it's a syntax file since I already updated. Any idea why that's happen? Also let me know if you want me to send the output of :scr for .c and .py file.

Comment: @markf:  I dont mind taking a look, although i am not a mac guy (i only have an old leopard).  i may have to ask more thing so better do that with email (my profile has my address).  its not really a programming problem so hope this will not upset people... (i am fairly new here)

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I couldn't find your email from your profile. I didn't want to post my email here (public) so I created one. My email is mytempfw from gmail dot com. If you can send me your email. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @markfw:  i sent you a mail shortly after your comment here.  so pls check the acct.

Answer (score 7):

The way that I made it to work (I'm using Terminal) is to have `let python_highlight_all = 1`
in my ~/.vimrc file and now everything works fine and all objects such as list, tuple, ... are colored.

For more information please look at the syntax/python.vim.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add the following lines to your ~/.vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
filetype on
syntax enabled
```

Quit and relaunch Vim or execute `:so ~/.vimrc` to reload the settings.

`nocompatible` remove compatibility with the original vi, this is recommended to get a fully functional Vim.
`filetype on` activate automatic file type detection, this is the option you want for your Python code to be colored.
`syntax enabled` activate code coloring, but i'm not sure if this is mandatory here.

You can get some more help by typing `:help filetype` in Vim.

Comment: @ Nicolas, thanks for your response. From my original post I had filetype and syntax on. I added set nocompatible and still it's not working.